# python: how to import a module a.b as a_.b?

Tags: python, python-import

I hava a package a and the tree is:

```
a/
  /__init__.py
  /b.py
```

And how can I `import a.b as a_.b` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to do it in two lines:

```
import a as a_
from a import b

print(a_.b)
# <module 'a.b' from '.\\a\\b.py'>
```

Or:

```
import a as a_
import a.b

print(a_.b)
# <module 'a.b' from '.\\a\\b.py'>
```

The first has the disadvantage that it puts `b` into your namespace and the second has the disadvantage that it puts `a` into your namespace.  If you want to, you can fix that by using `del b` and `del a`, respectively.

Alternatively, you can also write the second line as `from a import b as _` or `import a.b as _`, respectively, which will prevent `b` and `a` from appearing in your namespace.

Comment: Is the second line (`import a.b`) necessary?

Comment: depends on how the module is set up - if a explicitly imports pieces of b, no; but if not you'll need to import it so that it's more than a stub.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to register the name a_ in the sys.modules dictionary:

```
import sys
import a as a_
sys.modules['a_'] = a_
import a_.b
```

*Warning*: Doing this registers `a_` globally for this python session, so any other modules that try to `import a_` will end up with `a`.

For your particular case this is probably a bad way to go about this because of the global impact.  This can however be useful when a global rename is desired.